# login/logout with AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am trying to login and logout using AJAX in ASP.Net MVC. When I register and login it works. After login it redirects me to my home page (which is correct) but it does not show the Welcome email and Logout link. What I am missing in code?

Contoller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(Models.Registration userr)
{
    //if (ModelState.IsValid)
    //{
    if (IsValid(userr.Email, userr.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userr.Email, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
    }
    return View(userr);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Models.Registration user)
{
    try
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
          using (var db = new ApartManagementSystem.DAL.ApartContext())
          {
             var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
             var encrypPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);
             var newUser = db.Registrations.Create();
             newUser.Email = user.Email;
             newUser.Password = encrypPass;
             newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
             newUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
             newUser.LastName = user.LastName;
             newUser.UserType = "User";
             newUser.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
             newUser.IsActive = true;
             newUser.IPAddress = "642 White Hague Avenue";
             db.Registrations.Add(newUser);
             db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
          }
       }
       else
       {
          ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is not correct");
       }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
           eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
           foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
           {
              Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
           }
        }
       throw;
     }
     return View();
}



@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
   @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOut", "User")
}
else
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "User")
    <span> | </span>
    @Html.ActionLink("Log In", "LogIn", "User")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the Authentication ticket status is not saving in the context. Please check that you have something like this in your config file

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
   </authentication>
</system.web>
```

and this block should be removed if it exist :

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" /> <----****
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

EDIT: here is where your webconfig file is locate [image]
You can also check this link about configuration [authentication Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Shoul I add web.config ?I tried and I couldnt add.It gives error: Xml documnent cannot contain root level elements

Comment: I update my answer. In Asp.net mvc project there is already a file in the root folder called web.config. You have to open and edit it. The is no need to create a new config file.